# Is there a way to colour a row in a QTable depending on a bool value?

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtstylesheets

I have a QTable and each row gets a bool value. Each row with the value "true" should be highlighted. The value depends on the users input.
Can anyone help me? Thank in advance

Comment: What kind of table it is: `QTableWidget` or `QTableView`? Please show how do you create the table.

Comment: FYI: [Qt: Star Delegate Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-stardelegate-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

```
QTreeWidget *treeWidget;
treeWidget = new QTreeWidget(parentPtr);
QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->treeWidget);
item->setBackgroundColor(0, QColor(255, 255, 255));
item->setBackgroundColor(1, QColor(255, 255, 255));
```